# Resolve variable in function call in R

Tags: r, data-science, tidyr

I want to use a call to tidyr's `gather()` within a user-defined function. The code looks like this:

```
load_and_prepare_data <- function(xls_file, metric_name) {
  xl <- read_excel(xls_file)
  xl <- gather(xl, key = "year", value = metric_name, 2:ncol(xl), convert = TRUE)
  return(xl)
}
```

The problem is, that the variable `metric_name` is not resolved, but instead interpreted literally as string:

```
data <- load_and_prepare_data("indicator_lung_cancer.xls", "cancer")
```

After this a call to `names(data)` gives `[...] "year" "metric_name"` instead of `[...] "year" "cancer"`.

What do I need to change in order to pass a variable column name to the function? What is the reason for R's behavior?

Comment: Did you have a look at gather_() which uses standard evaluation and is recommended for programming with?

Comment: gather_ is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tidyr used function like `gather_` to help with these programming cases.
This is now deprecated, read [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).
 use `!!` to say that you want to unquote an input so that it’s evaluated.

```
load_and_prepare_data <- function(xls_file, metric_name) {
  xl <- read_excel(xls_file)  
  xl <- gather(xl, key = year, value = !!metric_name, 2:ncol(xl))
  return(xl)
}
```